# Detecting if the selected JComboBox item is enabled or disabled

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a JComboBox filled with some random items, that can change at run time. I have set them as JLabels using getListCellRendererComponent(...). I have also set some of those Jlabels as setEnabled( false ).

When user selects an item from that JComboBox, **is there a way i can detect if it is enabled or disabled ?**

Comment: maybe I'm misunderstanding your description but ... never add _components_ as items. You don't - do you?

Comment: @kleopatra: Yes, i do ... Is there a problem doing this ? I need to put icons + disable some items.

Comment: the problem is mixing separate concerns (which swing goes a long way to keep separated - that's why there are renderers ;-). See my answer as to how to design more swingishly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The renederer just paints them so there will not be an isEnabled value to check.  Instead use the same logic that the cellRenderer uses to determine if a value is allowed, when you are looking at the selection.  Or possibly remove those values from the list instead of making the disabled.

Comment: And of course if you use 'the same logic' this means extract it into a method and call that method.

Comment: Using the same logic was my alternate solution. I hoped there'd be another way.

Answer (score 1):

The items in the list/combo (or any of the collections components) are supposed to be representations of business objects with some state. Then implement renderers which are aware of the different state and make them (the renderer) map the state into appropriate visual representation.

```
// the item
public class Valve {
   private boolean open;
   private boolean canOperate;
   private Point location;
   // getters and methods as appropriate
   public boolean isOpen() { ...
   ...     
}

// custom renderer
Component getListCellRendererComponent(....) {
    // normal config, assuming you subclass DefaultListCellRender 
    super.getListCellRendererComponent(...)
    if (value instanceof Valve) {
        configFromValve((Valve) value)
    }  
    return this;
}
private void configFromValve(Valve valve) {
    setText("P: (" + valve.location().x + "," + valve.getLocation().y + ")");
    setIcon(valve.isOpen() ? openIcon : closedIcon);
    setEnabled(valve.canOperate());
}
```

Comment: I like your implementation a lot ... But may i ask(Just to understand), what's wrong with defining components as items in the combo model ?

Comment: @brad it's wrong to do so as a kludge to have some object with accidentally the properties you need. It might be okay if components _are_ your business objects (as might be f.i. in a visual builder), but that's really rare.